Python colab error only with GPU running instead of CPU
I'm trying to follow the example for generating synthetic images in this article
(https://medium.com/@sofeikov/implementing-variational-autoencoders-from-scratch-533782d8eb95)  about variational autoencoders and the code runs normally, but when I try to switch on T4-GPU running it gives me this error. I don't know also why the generating images are all the same and they are all too bad...in the article the reconstructed images are pretty good. I tried to switch it back and the error disappear.
import numpy as np
import gzip
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch
def show_images(images, labels):
    """
    Display a set of images and their labels using matplotlib.
    The first column of `images` should contain the image indices,
    and the second column should contain the flattened image pixels
    reshaped into 28x28 arrays.
    """
    # Extract the image indices and reshaped pixels
    pixels = images.reshape(-1, 28, 28)

    # Create a figure with subplots for each image
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(
        ncols=len(images), nrows=1, figsize=(10, 3 * len(images))
    )

    # Loop over the images and display them with their labels
    for i in range(len(images)):
        # Display the image and its label
        axs[i].imshow(pixels[i], cmap="gray")
        axs[i].set_title("Label: {}".format(labels[i]))

        # Remove the tick marks and axis labels
        axs[i].set_xticks([])
        axs[i].set_yticks([])
        axs[i].set_xlabel("Index: {}".format(i))

    # Adjust the spacing between subplots
    fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)

    # Show the figure
    plt.show()



class AutoEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Set the number of hidden units
        self.num_hidden = 8

        # Define the encoder part of the autoencoder
        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(784, 256),  # input size: 784, output size: 256
            nn.ReLU(),  # apply the ReLU activation function
            nn.Linear(256, self.num_hidden),  # input size: 256, output size: num_hidden
            nn.ReLU(),  # apply the ReLU activation function
        )

        # Define the decoder part of the autoencoder
        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(self.num_hidden, 256),  # input size: num_hidden, output size: 256
            nn.ReLU(),  # apply the ReLU activation function
            nn.Linear(256, 784),  # input size: 256, output size: 784
            nn.Sigmoid(),  # apply the sigmoid activation function to compress the output to a range of (0, 1)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        # Pass the input through the encoder
        encoded = self.encoder(x)
        # Pass the encoded representation through the decoder
        decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
        # Return both the encoded representation and the reconstructed output
        return encoded, decoded



dir_path = r'/content'

# List to store files
filenames = []

# Iterate directory
for path in os.listdir(dir_path):
    # Check if current path is a file
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path, path)):
        filenames.append(os.path.join(dir_path, path))  # Store full path

data = []
for filename in filenames:
    with gzip.open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        if 'labels' in filename:
            # Load the labels as a one-dimensional array of integers
            data.append(np.frombuffer(f.read(), np.uint8, offset=8))
        else:
            # Load the images as a two-dimensional array of pixels
            data.append(np.frombuffer(f.read(), np.uint8, offset=16).reshape(-1, 28*28))

# Split into training and testing sets
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = data

# Normalize the pixel values
X_train = X_train.astype(np.float32) / 255.0
X_test = X_test.astype(np.float32) / 255.0

# Convert labels to integers
y_train = y_train.astype(np.int64)
y_test = y_test.astype(np.int64)
show_images(X_train[:5], y_train[:5])

# Convert the training data to PyTorch tensors
X_train = torch.from_numpy(X_train)

learning_rate = 20
batch_size = 16
# Create the autoencoder model and optimizer
model = AutoEncoder()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

# Define the loss function
criterion = nn.MSELoss()

# Set the device to GPU if available, otherwise use CPU


# Create a DataLoader to handle batching of the training data
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    X_train, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True
)

num_epochs = 10
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    total_loss = 0.0
    for batch_idx, data in enumerate(train_loader):
        # Get a batch of training data and move it to the device

        # Forward pass
        encoded, decoded = model(data)

        # Compute the loss and perform backpropagation
        loss = criterion(decoded, data)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # Update the running loss
        total_loss += loss.item() * data.size(0)

    # Print the epoch loss
    epoch_loss = total_loss / len(train_loader.dataset)
    print(
        "Epoch {}/{}: loss={:.4f}".format(epoch + 1, num_epochs, epoch_loss)
    )
def generate_images(model, images, num_images=5):
    """
    Pass images through the autoencoder model to generate and display reconstructed images.
    """
    with torch.no_grad():  # No need to compute gradients during inference
        _, decoded_images = model(images[:num_images])

    decoded_images = decoded_images.reshape(-1, 28, 28).numpy()
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, num_images, figsize=(10, 4))

    for i in range(num_images):
        axs[0, i].imshow(images[i].reshape(28, 28), cmap="gray")
        axs[0, i].set_title("Original")
        axs[0, i].axis("off")

        axs[1, i].imshow(decoded_images[i], cmap="gray")
        axs[1, i].set_title("Reconstructed")
        axs[1, i].axis("off")
    plt.show()

generate_images(model, X_train[:5])



I get this error.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-8a9cc0526602> in <cell line: 106>()
    104 y_train = y_train.astype(np.int64)
    105 y_test = y_test.astype(np.int64)
--> 106 show_images(X_train[:5], y_train[:5])
    107 
    108 # Convert the training data to PyTorch tensors

<ipython-input-13-8a9cc0526602> in show_images(images, labels)
     14     """
     15     # Extract the image indices and reshaped pixels
---> 16     pixels = images.reshape(-1, 28, 28)
     17 
     18     # Create a figure with subplots for each image

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 5 into shape (28,28)

And when I try to comment the function I get this error..I can't stand how only changing the runtime
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-5168ebd0ea82> in <cell line: 129>()
    133 
    134         # Forward pass
--> 135         encoded, decoded = model(data)
    136 
    137         # Compute the loss and perform backpropagation

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py in forward(self, input)
    123 
    124     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 125         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
    126 
    127     def extra_repr(self) -> str:

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1x16 and 784x256)

